# Is it permissible to touch a child of the opposite sex?

Tags: children, non-mahram, touching

Is it permissible for a man , who has hit puberty, to touch a non mehram, who has not hit the puberty? She is still a girl in that sense, so is it haram?

Answer (score 1):

It is permissible to touch a young child of the opposite sex who is not close to the age of puberty.

However, if there is a fear of falling prey to sexual desires or if the child is close to puberty, it will not be permissible to touch such people.

Source :

الأصل للشيباني ط قطر (2/ 236)

ولا ينبغي له أن يمس يدها ولا وجهها  إذا كانت شابة ممن تُشتهَى. فأما إذا كانت عجوزاً ممن لا تُشتهَى فلا بأس بمصافحتها ومس يدها. وإن كان  عليها ثياب فلا بأس بأن يتأملها أو يتأمل  جسدها ما لم تكن ثياب تصفها. فإن كانت ثيابها تلزق بجسدها حتى يستبين له جسدها فينبغي له أن يغض بصره عن ذلك. وإن كانت ثيابها لا تصف شيئاً من جسدها فلا بأس بالنظر إليها؛ لأنه إنما ينظر إلى الثياب وإلى القامة فلا بأس بذلك

المحيط البرهاني في الفقه النعماني (5/ 335)

فإن كانت عجوزاً لا تشتهى فلا بأس بمصافحتها، ومس يدها، والأصل في ذلك ما روي أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم كان يصافح العجائز في البيعة، ولا يصافح الشواب، ولأن الحرمة في الشواب لخوف الفتنة، ولا خوف في العجائز، وكذلك إذا كان شيخاً يأمن على نفسه وعليها فلا بأس بأن يصافحها، وإن كان لا يأمن على نفسه أو عليها، فليجتنب لما مر من قبل هذا.

ثم إن محمداً رحمه الله أباح المس للرجال إذا كانت المرأة عجوزاً، ولم يشترط كون الرجل بحال لا يجامع مثله فيما إذا كان الماس هي المرأة، قال: إذا كانا كبيرين لا يجامع مثله، ولا يجامع مثلها، فلا بأس بالمصافحة، فليأمل عند الفتوى

نفحات السلوك على تحفة الملوك (ص: 390)

ولا يَحِلُّ للشابّ مسُّ الوجه والكفين وإن أَمِنَ الشهوة إلا من عجوز لا تشتهى، فتَحِلُّ المصافحةُ ونحوها، وكذا لو كان شيخاً وأَمِنَ عليه وعليها، فإن خاف عليها حَرُم

والصغيرةُ التي لا تشتهى يَحِلّ مسُّها

الهداية في شرح بداية المبتدي (4/ 368)

أما إذا كانت عجوزا لا تشتهى فلا بأس بمصافحتها ومس يدها لانعدام خوف الفتنة. وقد روي أن أبا بكر رضي الله عنه كان يدخل بعض القبائل التي كان مسترضعا فيهم وكان يصافح العجائز، وعبد الله بن الزبير رضي الله عنه استأجر عجوزا لتمرضه، وكانت تغمز رجليه وتفلي رأسه، وكذا إذا كان شيخا يأمن على نفسه وعليها لما قلنا، فإن كان لا يأمن عليها لا تحل مصافحتها لما فيه من التعريض للفتنة. والصغيرة إذا كانت لا تشتهى يباح مسها والنظر إليها لعدم خوف الفتنة

“والصغيرة إذا كانت لاتشتهي يباح مسها والنظر إليها” لعدم خوف الفتنة

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the motive of the touch. If it is just casual touch with no sexual feelings, then there is nothing wrong in it. But if the touch has sexual feelings then it is not allowed

> Say, "**My Lord has only forbidden immoralities - what is apparent of
> them and what is concealed** - and sin, and oppression without right,
> and that you associate with Allah that for which He has not sent down
> authority, and that you say about Allah that which you do not know." [Quran 7:33](https://legacy.quran.com/7/33)

Also, we are instructed to not come near any shameful deeds

> Say, ˹O Prophet,˺ “Come! Let me recite to you what your Lord has
> forbidden to you: do not associate others with Him ˹in worship˺. ˹Do
> not fail to˺ honour your parents. Do not kill your children for fear
> of poverty. We provide for you and for them. **Do not come near
> indecencies, openly or secretly.** Do not take a ˹human˺ life—made
> sacred by Allah—except with ˹legal˺ right.1 This is what He has
> commanded you, so perhaps you will understand. [Quran 6:151](https://quran.com/en/al-anam/151)